# Install Ubuntu on an external SSD

Tags: system-installation, ssd, external-hdd

I've been unable to install OSX onto an SSD (I tried two different drives, internally and externally), and I'd now like to see if installing Ubuntu might work. I have a Dell Inspiron running Ubuntu, and I have a USB external drive adapter. How can I install Ubuntu onto an SSD using the USB adapter connected to my Dell? I believe the adapter is USB 2.0, if that matters. I took it out of an external HD enclosure.

Comment: Skip to the section **run the installer** to *find* your answer

Comment: Be aware that trim may fail to run over USB for the SSD in an external enclosure.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/496142)

Comment: Well,  I did include the essential parts of the answer... 



"Just use the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator."



If the link becomes invalid, future referers can always google "Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator" and the updated reply will come out.